# MUI Change ListItemText styles when active in react-router

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using `ListItem` from MUI. I am trying to make it bolder when it is active but seems `font-weight` doesn't work.

See below for the code.

```
<List
      component='nav'
      aria-label='main mailbox folders'
    >
      <ListItem
        button
        component={NavLink}
        exact
        to='/accounts'
        activeClassName={classes.active}
        className={classes.appBarNavButtons}
      >
        <MyAccountsIcon />
        <ListItemText
          style={{ marginLeft: '20px', fontSize: 'large' }}
          primary='My Accounts'
        />
      </ListItem>
</List>
```

Style:

```
appBarNavButtons: {
  color: colors.blueGrey[800],
  textTransform: 'none',
  letterSpacing: 0,
},
active: {
  color: '#0056b3',
  fontWeight: 'bolder',
  '& $icon': {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  }
}
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**V5**

In v5, the `button` prop of `ListItem` and `makeStyles` are deprecated. The alternatives are `ListItemButton` and `styled` as demonstrated from the example below:

```
import MuiListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const ListItemButton = styled(MuiListItemButton)({
  '&.active .MuiTypography-root': {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

```
<ListItem disablePadding>
  <ListItemButton component={NavLink} exact to="/">
    <ListItemText primary="Home" />
  </ListItemButton>
</ListItem>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

Your styles has lower priority than the one from `Typography` inside the `ListItem`, you can override it by using nested selector to increase the CSS specificity:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  active: {
    '& .MuiTypography-root': {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  },
});
```

```js
<ListItem
  button
  component={NavLink}
  exact
  to="/"
  activeClassName={classes.active}
>
  <ListItemText primary="Home" />
</ListItem>
```

[image: Edit 64587811/react-material-ui-listitemtext-make-bolder-when-active]

Comment: Hey man @NearHuscarl, big thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it still doesn't make the text bolder. I'll try to add .active and see if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ohhimarccc I've updated my answer. I was using the wrong css selector. Sorry.

Comment: Hey @NearHuscarl, it works! Thank you so much for the big help!